# HTTPS configuration, SSL

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, https

I'm currently configuring LibreNMS with HTTPS, and have followed this guide for setting up HTTPS:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-18-04

The default-ssl.conf file contains this section:

```
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
         SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
```

However in the HTTP virtual host file for the LibreNMS site this section exist:

```
<Directory "/opt/librenms/html/">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</Directory>
```

So what I've done is that I have copied the `directory` section from the LibreNMS HTTP virtual host into the `default-ssl.conf` file, so that the `default-ssl.conf` virtual host contains both the original `directory` and the one from the LibreNMS HTTP virtual host.

Everything seems to work just fine `sudo apache2ctl configtest` passes and I can access the LibreNMS site using HTTPS (cert visible etc). But since I'm not that experienced with Linux I'm wondering if having two "directory" sections in the same virtual host file will pose any possible problems?

For example is the second `directory` section overwriting the information of the first when the file is read, and if so what is the implications of not using the `directory` section which exist in the `default-ssl.conf` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple directory options is fully supported. A site may have many directories, to which different settings shall be applied.

If it's for testing and development, running everything under the default site is not really problematic. However, it may limit your ability to run further sites, depending on your set up. If it's production, I would suggest to set up a proper VirtualHost for each and every site.